# I am trying to find an element within a <frame> using testcafe but i am unable to do so. is there a method to get this done please?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

i have tried the following :

```
t.switchTo("frameID");
var ele = Selector("#ele");
await t.click(ele);
```

another attempt :

```
Selector(() =>{return document.getElementById("frameId").contentDocument.getElementById("#ele")});
```

This throws the following error : Function for selector should return DomElement, NodeList, HtmlCollection, NULL or undefined.

The HTML DOM is as follows :

```
<html>
<body>
<frameset>
<frame id='frame1'>
#document
<html>
<body>
<p id='ele1'>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share HTML DOM of your page you want to test?

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have edited my question to include the HTML DOM of the page.

Comment: I hope you are using t.switchTo("frame1") instead of t.switchTo("frameID") as actual value of frame id is frame1. I can not see any other error apart from this.

Answer (score 0):

The `frame` and `frameset` features are marked as [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) in the W3C Recommendation. As TestCafe is based on HTML5 standards that do not support `frameset`, TestCafe does not support `frameset` either. So, we'd like to focus on up-to-date features, which will give the best experience in testing modern web applications.

As for the example you shared, you can use this test:

```
test('test', async t => {
    await t.click('#ele1');
})
```